# ANT | Trying to override old definition of task javac Error

Tags: xml, ant

i am trying to build a jar in ANT.Below is my code for generating jar file.i dont know why this error("Trying to override old definition of task javac") happens.sometimes its not generating jar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<project name="HelloWorld" default="compress">

    <presetdef name="javac">
            <javac includeantruntime="false" />
    </presetdef>

    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
        <mkdir dir="dist" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes"/>
    </target>  

    <target name="compress" depends="compile">
            <jar destfile="dist/sample.jar" basedir="build/classes" />

    </target>

    <target name="execute" depends="compile">
        <java classname="src" classpath="build/classes" />
    </target> 

    <target name="clean">

    </target>

</project>
```

The output is as follows:

```
Buildfile: E:\GAD project\project\GAD\build.xml
Trying to override old definition of task javac
init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: E:\GAD project\project\GAD\dist
compile:
compress:
      [jar] Building jar: E:\GAD project\project\GAD\dist\sample.jar
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Let me know how can i rectify the error msg.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lets try this

```
<presetdef name="my.javac">
            <javac includeantruntime="false" />
    </presetdef>


    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <my.javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes"/>
    </target>
```

Comment: :Excellent.it went off.but generating jar takes some time.can you please suggest me on that.jar size is of about 1909 kb

Answer (score 1):

In general it happens when ant tasks are loaded multiple times from different sources.
For example:

```
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${location1}/ant-contrib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${location2}/ant-contrib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="ping">
        <echo message="pong"/>
    </target>
```

```
Output:
..
Trying to override old definition of task addCredentials
Trying to override old definition of task clearCredentials
Trying to override old definition of task purgeExpiredCookies
Trying to override old definition of task postMethod
Trying to override old definition of task getMethod
Trying to override old definition of task headMethod
Trying to override old definition of task importurl
ping:
     [echo] pong
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the following import in my build.xml which was causing the issues

```
<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
```